# Web scraping Button BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, class, button, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to webscrape the span from a button that has a determinated class. This is the code of the page on the website.

```
<button class="sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5    " type="button">altri <span>17</span></button>
```

I'd like to find "17" that obviously changes everytime. Thanks.
I've tried with this one but it doesn't work

```
for item in soup.find_all('button', {'class': 'sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5    '}):
```

Comment: Use selectors. The selector `button.sqdOP span` will select this span.

Comment: thanks, where should i put it?

Comment: `soup.select('<selector here>')`

Comment: yes, but i need the span in the button that has this specific class.

Comment: This selects the span.

Comment: sorry, i've just started and i don't understand where should i put the selector... can you help me rewriting the code that is wrong? as answer can be really good because i will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

For complex selections, it's best to use *selectors*. These work very similar to CSS.

`p` selects an element with the type `p`.

`p.example` selects an element with type `p` and class `example`.

`p span` selects any `span` inside a `p`.

There are also others, but only these are needed for this example.

These can be nested as you like. For example, `p.example span.foo` selects any `span` with class `foo` inside any `p` with class `example`.

Now, an element can have multiple classes, and they are separated by spaces. `<p class="foo bar">Hello, World!</p>` has both `foo` and `bar` as class.

I think I am safe to assume the class `sqdOP` is unique. You can build the selector pretty easily using the above:

```
button.sqdOP span
```

Now, issue `select`, and BeautifulSoup will return a list of matching elements. If this is the only one, you can safely use `[0]` to get the first item. So, the final code to select that `span`:

```py
soup.select('button.sqdOP span')[0]
```

Comment: @pythonchanger Whoops. If you want to iterate through _all of them_, don't use `[0]`.

Comment: do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @pythonchanger can you send me the code you use to fetch the webpage and create the soup instance? I'll experiment with it locally.

Comment: `try:
        sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(msg['text']).read()
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')

        for item in soup.select('button.sqdOP span')[0]:
            #answer = ''.join(filter(whitelist.__contains__, item.text))
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, item)

    except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
        if err.code == 404:
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Link del post non corretto, incolla un link di questo tipo: https://www.instagram.com/p/xxxxx")

`

Comment: idk why stack changes all the tabulations

Comment: @pythonchanger `msg['text']` please

Comment: msg['text'] is the link that the user insert, is an instagram post link